# JavaFX BarChart bar color

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

How can you change the color of a bar in a JavaFX `BarChart`?

I couldn't find a way to change the color through the css `setStyle` Method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set color of bar using css

```
.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: ***** }
.default-color1.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: ***** }
...
```

Using setStyle Method :

use  [lookupAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll%28java.lang.String%29) method in Node class,

> Finds all Nodes, including this one and any children, which match the
>   given CSS selector. If no matches are found, an empty unmodifiable set
>   is returned. The set is explicitly unordered.

code :

```
  //set first bar color
  for(Node n:barChart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar")) {
            n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: red;");
        }
   //second bar color
   for(Node n:barChart.lookupAll(".default-color1.chart-bar")) {
            n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: green;");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I do this with the setStyle Method?

Answer (score 1):

From JavaFX8 you can simply use the `.chart-bar` selector:

```
.chart-bar {
    -fx-bar-fill: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click in the Category axis or Number axis (which one you want to change color) > go the the editor (right side of scene builder) > choose color in tick label fill

[image]