# How to color BarChart bar in TornadoFx?

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying to change the colours/shading of the bar chart bars in TornadoFX using a custom stylesheet.

I came across this post: [JavaFX BarChart bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158104/javafx-barchart-color) which uses the `-fx-bar-fill` selector but I'm having a hard time translating this into a form that TornadoFX will accept.

Here's my stylesheet:

```
class BarChartStyles : Stylesheet(){

  companion object {
      val histogramChart by cssclass()
      val backColor = c("#4682B4")
  }

  init{
      histogramChart{
          defaultColor0{
              chartBar{
                  barFill = backColor
              }
          }     
      }
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm declaring the `BarChart`:

```
barchart("my histogram", CategoryAxis(), NumberAxis()){

            barGap = 0.0
            categoryGap = 0.0

            hgrow = Priority.ALWAYS
            vgrow = Priority.ALWAYS

            style{
                minWidth = 640.px
                minHeight = 240.px
                maxHeight = 480.px
            }

            addClass(BarChartStyles.histogramChart)

            series("Portfolio 1") {
                data("1", 23)
                data("2", 14)
                data("3", 15)
                data("4", 23)
                data("5", 14)
                data("6", 15)
                data("7", 23)
                data("8", 14)
                data("9", 15)
                data("10", 23)
                data("11", 14)
                data("12", 15)
                data("13", 23)
                data("14", 14)
                data("15", 15)
                data("16", 23)
                data("17", 14)
                data("18", 15)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without TornadoFX you could use the `.chart-bar` selector in your stylesheet without defining any custom CSS classes:

```
.chart-bar {
    -fx-bar-fill: #4682B4; 
}
```

The TornadoFX equivalent is:

```
class BarChartStyles : Stylesheet() {

    companion object {
        val backColor = c("#4682B4")
        val chartBar by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        chartBar {
            barFill = backColor
        }
    }
}
```

After applying the style your example looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does work in my main window! My issue now is that I'm attempting to open these histograms in new stages and I don't think the stylesheet is being imported - but that's another matter.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it's another question, but for that you'll find definitely answers on SO :)